# How do I update an Eclipse template variable on the fly?

Tags: eclipse, templates, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I've added the following new Eclipse template via extension point. It simply adds a template for a sample *testTag* tag.

```xml
<!-- Add code template -->
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates">
   <template autoinsert="true"
             contextTypeId="html_tag"
             description="[Description] Template populated by Snippet values ***"
             id="org.eclipse.jst.jsf.ui.newHtmltag"
             name="testTag">
       <pattern>
            <![CDATA[
                <testTag style="background: ${color}"></testTag> 
            ]]>
       </pattern>
   </template>
  <resolver
     contextTypeId="html_tag"
     type="src" 
     class="TestTagTemplateVariableResolver">
  </resolver>
</extension>
```

What I'd cannot figure out is how to change the value of the $(color) variable at runtime. More specifically, when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (or the equivalent for content-assist) and types in "testTag" and presses Enter -- instead of the "color" placeholder text, I'd like it replaced by some other text value I have in another class. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm a little confused - you have provided an implementation of `TestTagTemplateVariableResolver`, which extends `TemplateVariableResolver` and implements `resolve()`, but it still doesn't work?  Could you post more code or more details?

Answer (score 1):

[This email chain from 2004](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg10617.html) says it might not be possible:

> the Java editor chooses not to respect resolvers contributed to its two context types ('java' and 'javadoc'), but only recognizes the built-in resolvers.

The html editor you are working with may have a similar restriction.