# How to build a Template like javadoc in jdt and cdt

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-templates

I am trying to incorporate feature similar to JavaDoc in my Java and C/C++ editor. Suppose I type "ABC" and press enter, it should be auto completed as

```
 
   /*
    * ABCD
    * XYZ
    * 1234
    */
```

I have to do it programmatically. What are the ways that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link should help [Add Java code template programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005003/add-java-code-template-programmatically)

You can set the context of the template as 'JavaDoc'

If not programmatically then you can go to preferences->Java->Editor->Templates.
And create a new template.

cheers,
Saurav